# How to set space between for last 2 element in wrap

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. I want to build a layout like below.
For the part 1 and Part 2 is correct and what i want.

But for the part 3, i want to set space between for the bbbb & cccc element. But i try to flex / row / wrap the last 2 elements still not what i want.

Is anyone has any idea for the goal? Thank you

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: const Text('Part 1'),
                  ),
                  Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const Text('bbbbbbbb'),
                      ),
                      Container(color: Colors.green, child: const Text('cccccccc')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: const Text('Part 2'),
                  ),
                  Flex(
                    // alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    // runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text(
                              'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(color: Colors.green, child: const Text('cccccccc')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: const Text('Part 3'),
                  ),
                  Flex(
                    // alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    // runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(color: Colors.green, child: const Text('cccccccc')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) to provide space between widgets on third snippet or to provide fixed space use `SizedBox`.

```dart
              Flex(
                      direction: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: const Text(
                                'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.green, child: const Text('cccccccc')),
                      ],
                    ),
```

**Result**
[image]

**Prefer With Column and Wrap**

```dart
   return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              /// 1st one
              /// second one
              SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: const Text('Part 3'),
                    ),
                    Wrap(
                      alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text('bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb'),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.green, child: const Text('cccccccc')),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**With Column**
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if using spacer, bbbb in part 3 will be shorter.

Comment: In this case I would prefer using Column and Wrap/Row to create the view.

Comment: yes, i know, but my concern for this is i don't know length  of 'bbbbb', it depends on user's input.

Comment: does update answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

May consider adding `SizedBox` between them.

```dart
                  Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const Text('bbbbbbbb'),
                      ),
                      // add some space using SizedBox
                      SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                      Container(color: Colors.green, child: const Text('cccccccc')),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: thank you , but hard code the width is not good for responsive layout.